# How to make a colorplot from a given 2-D array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been coding a search tree for uniform-search, A*-search and greedy search and am required to make a 2-D plot of the path that the searches take when finding the goal.

An example 2-D array looks like this:

```
grid = array([
    [2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,3,3,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
    [2,1,3,3,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
    [2,1,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
    [2,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
    [2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
    [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

I need to know how to colour each of the blocks in the color plot according to what value is stored in a specific block ie :

```
if 0 -> white
if 1 -> black
if 2 -> blue
if 3 -> yellow
```

I have no experience with python 2-d graph plotting. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib (or other packages).  Check out the hist2d function.
There are many examples here:
http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

Some of which you'd probably find useful.